# How can i write a publisher for /GPSFix message from Velodyne Lidar?

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am working with lidar and QGIS. i need to take /GPSFix meassage from velodyne lidar and   mark its GPS position in QGIS map. In QGIS i have to write a plugin but for that i need to subscribe /GPSFix meassage from lidar.

Is it possible?

if so how to implement it? can anyone help? pls

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69442/how-can-i-write-a-publisher-for-/gpsfix-message-from-velodyne-lidar?/) by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found. This is the code.

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <gps_common/GPSFix.h>

void GPSCallback(const gps_common::GPSFix::ConstPtr& msg)
{
std::cout<<"Latitude: "<<msg->latitude<<"\t"<<"Longitude: "<<msg->longitude<<"\n";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  
  ros::init(argc, argv, "listener");

 
  ros::NodeHandle n;


  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/GPSFix", 1000, GPSCallback);

  
  ros::spin();

  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) with karma: 26 on 2013-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiy1991](https://answers.ros.org/users/23665/weiy1991/) on 2015-09-07**:
Can /GPSFix be published by gpsd_client from Garmin 18 LVC?